# Will onCreate called after onStop without onDestroy in the middle

Tags: android, multithreading

Will onCreate called after onStop without onDestroy in the middle?

From the picture below, the answer is YES.

[image: Activity Life Cycle]

But in the [same page](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/Activity.html), it says:

> protected void onStop() 
>   Called when you are no longer visible to the
>   user. You will next receive either onRestart(), onDestroy(), or
>   nothing, depending on later user activity.

My app need to run a background task even if the user leave to another app or turn off the screen. The only situation where the task should be stopped is that the app is entirely closed. So I create and run the background thread in `onCreate()` and stop it in `onDestroy()`. The problem I am facing is that sometimes there are more than one of my threads running at the same time. This often happens when I leave my app for a long time then back. I think it may due to multiple calls of `onCreate()`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will onCreate called after onStop without onDestroy in the middle?

Short answer: **No**

Long answer:

`onCreate` won't be called if just `onStop` has been called on an `activity`. After `onStop` if user navigates back to activity, it's `onStart` (before that `onRestart` will also be called) will be called.

[image]

Now let me explain how `onCreate` will be called after `onStop` without `onDestroy` being called.

For that you need to look at this **process priority hierarchy** in android:

[image]

Activity remains in **foreground processes** from the time `onResume` has been called but `onPause` hasn't been called. And since foreground processes has highest priority, it won't get killed.

`onPause` is called when **user is no longer able to interact with the `activity` but it is VISIBLE**. Example: when you open a `DialogFragment` above the activity. Then activity process moves into **visible process**. This has lesser priority than foreground process but has enough priority to not get killed.

Not after that comes `onStop`, which is called when **user is no longer able to see the activity** that means activity is **not visible**.
That comes the point when activity process moves into background processes. Now it can be killed if system need more memory and your activity is consuming more memory than others (this is off-topic of this answer that which background is first to get killed).

So if an activity which is in background and is killed by the system, **`onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called**. And in that case, `onCreate` will be called after `onStop` without `onDestroy` being called.

[image]

That's why in the question image (activity lifecycle), it is shown that `onCreate` will be called after `onStop` if **App process is killed**.

Edit 1:

If you want to handle anything (like freeing up memory, killing memory intensive tasks, etc) before activity being destroyed and since `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called, you can implement [`ComponentCallbacks2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html)(only for api level >= 14) to receive [`onTrimMemory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory(int)) callback with varies stages of your application/activity. Varies stages and their explanations are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html).

If you want to implement the same in API level < 14, you can use [`onLowMemory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory()) callback which is roughly equivalent to [`TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE).

Comment: Your answer is helpful. onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called. Weird thing is that there isn't a method onKilled(), so it is impossible to handle all activity death events. I'm now learning how to use Service to solve my problem.

Comment: @JeffreyChen, Yes there are methods to get these callbacks, I have updated my answer, just go through it.

Answer (score 1):

> This often happens when I leave my app for a long time then back. I think it may due to multiple calls of onCreate(). How to solve it?

In `onCreate()` you can check if your background thread is running, if yes then don't start it again.

More importantly, is your background thread a `service` or `AsyncTask` or just simple `Thread`?

Considering the wording in your question i would recommend you to go for `service` if you are not already using it. It won't create "multiple thread" problem.

Comment: handler.postDelayed([The Runneable with its run() contain this line], SOME_PERIOD). So it runs periodically until a boolean flag set to true.

Comment: What if I start my task in the Service and then the Service is killed and recreated. It seems to produce "multiple thread" problem too.

Comment: @JeffreyChen If a service is running it won't run again. If the service is killed and your program starts it again, it is still running only one instance of that service.

Comment: But in my case, the Service spawn a worker thread every time it's recreated. Isn't it possible to have multiple worker threads run at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Service` to run a background task. If you want to stop the service when current activity destroys, you can use `Bind Service.`

Please Post your code snippet to get exact idea, how are you trying. we can help more